# Seat post tightening

Tags: seatpost

I have a Giant Defy 3 and I'm not sure how tight the seat post bolts should be. I don't have a torque Allen key. Is doing the two bolts on the ring that goes around the frame as tight as I can do them with my hands ok? It's an aluminium frame. I don't  I want to cause any damage to the frame.

Thanks

Comment: Be conservative.  Just enough the seat will not move.

Comment: With aluminium frame is there a worry that IF I did tighten more than just enough for the seat post not to move, would it cause damage?

Comment: Don't turn it 5 revolutions and then test.  Do 1/4 turn at a time.

Answer (score 1):

In this [manual](https://www.pedalon.co.uk/acatalog/Vector.pdf), they state the torque for the Giant Defy seatpost should be around 50kgf-cm (5Nm). I know this is for the carbon frame, but they should be similar.

You can buy a [torque wrench](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=torque%20wrench&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Atorque%20wrench) for around $30, which you should, because otherwise there is a high chance you will under or over tight it. I know $30 is a pain in the ass, but think this will keep your $1000 bike running smoothly for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

It does not take much torque to snug up the seat post.  With a long lever yes you could damage the frame.  Cross one finger over the Allen key so you have a short lever and snug it up.  See if you can twist the seat.  If so snug each up another 1/4 turn and test.